# libpng can’t find zlib

Tags: mingw, zlib, configure, libpng

As I did `./configure` for libpng-1.6.18 on MinGW following message was shown.

> configure: error: zlib not installed

I installed zlib-1.2.8 into `/usr/local` and tried `./configure` libpng again.

However, error wasn’t solved.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Try configuring both with `./configure --prefix=/mingw`

Comment: It works, thanks.I also changed profile to add PATH for new zlib I installed.